# How do I determine a device mentioned in "ld: final link failed: No space left on device" message during 'make'

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, make

I am trying to comlete make command when installing kernel 4.19.188-amd64.
But I get `No space left on device` after 2 hours after `make` command.
I increased /tmp folder, set TMPDIR to a folder in home directory but nothing helped.

Then I did `watch` command to monitor a space of /tmp, $TMPDIR, $TMPDIR in root environment and havn't notice any size increase at any of them.

Error:

```
  LD [M]  drivers/gpu/drm/mgag200/mgag200.ko
  LD [M]  drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nouveau.ko
  LD [M]  drivers/gpu/drm/qxl/qxl.ko
  LD [M]  drivers/gpu/drm/r128/r128.ko
  LD [M]  drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon.ko
ld: final link failed: No space left on device
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:129: drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
ld: final link failed: No space left on device
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:129: drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon.ko] Error 1
ld: final link failed: No space left on device
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:129: drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu.ko] Error 1
ld: final link failed: No space left on device
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:129: drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nouveau.ko] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:1262: modules] Error 2
u@ngff /media/u/fb07f3d2-e36b-4cfc-b671-cc9d7393f1d5/home/u/Downloads/linux-4.19.188
$ echo $TMPDIR
/home/u/temp
u@ngff /media/u/fb07f3d2-e36b-4cfc-b671-cc9d7393f1d5/home/u/Downloads/linux-4.19.188
$ du -sh $TMPDIR
4.0K    /home/u/temp
u@ngff /media/u/fb07f3d2-e36b-4cfc-b671-cc9d7393f1d5/home/u/Downloads/linux-4.19.188
```

Well I know that there are threads about 'No space left on device' but I did what they told and now want to know how to determine which device is used actually, just to watch it more.
These are commands before the error:

(as a user)

```
rm -rf linux-4.19.188 &&
tar xf linux-4.19.188.tar && ll &&
cd linux-4.19.188 &&
cp ../../../../boot/config-4.19.0-16-amd64 ./.config -v &&
sed -ri '/CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS/s/=.+/=""/g' .config &&
make -j 4
```

How much space would be enough? 100M, 1GB? How to determine the device?

Comment: Please add result of `df -h` to your question. Chances are it'll be obvious from that

Comment: The makefile should show where the final kernel would be stored (although the syntax may be hard to follow). I would expect it to be in /boot, which can be rather small. You might also find more informative "disk full" messages in /var/log/syslog.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was from too small main disk 32GB. Not tmp space. I did not expect that this process needed 16GB.